# GraphQL scheme delegation: info.mergeInfo is not defined

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I wonder if there is a catch to using `info.mergeInfo` when delegating a resolver. To explain what I'm trying to do let's assume a schema similar to:

```
type Repository {
    id: Int!
    commits: [Commit!]!
}
type Commit {
    id: Int!
    repository: Repository!
}
```

I'm trying to implement a query similar to:

```
query {
    RepositoryByCommit($id: Int!) {
        commit(id: $id) {
            repository {
                id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With a resolver like:

```
Query: {
    repository: (_, { id }) => db.getRepository(id),
    commit: (_, { id }) => db.getCommit(id)
},
Commit: {
    repository: (repository, args, context, info) {
        return info.mergeInfo.delegate({ // <-- mergeInfo is undefined here
            operation: 'query',
            fieldName: 'repository',
            args: {
                id: context.commitRawDBEntity.repositoryId
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Now according to [graphql-tools documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-stitching.html#adding-resolvers) there should be a set of functions available on `info.mergeInfo` for all resolvers. But in my case there is no property called `info.mergeInfo` nor anything similar.

It's worth to mention that I'm using `makeExecutableSchema` from `graphql-tools` to serve this GraphQL endpoint so I had the reason to assume that graphql-tools somehow would add that functionality to all resolvers.

Am I doing it all wrong? Why don't I have a `mergeInfo` object in my resolver? Are there better ways to achieve a resolution of parent entity?

Thanks !